# Date invalid Rails leap year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A person was born in 1988 Feb 29 a leap year. How to define this date - 1 day(Feb 28) when the year is not leap?

```
def valid_date
d = DateTime.parse("Feb. 29")
rescue ArgumentError  
d = "Invalid Date"
end
```

Comment: `Date.new(1888, 2, 29) - 1 => #<Date: 1888-02-28 ((2410696j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` is one way. Try to avoid using `parse` as it can yield unexpected results (`Date.parse "I may go to a movie." #=> #<Date: 2020-05-01 ((2458971j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`

Comment: You could also use [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime): `Date.strptime("Feb 29, 1888", "%b %d, %Y") - 1 #=> #<Date: 1888-02-28 ((2410696j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. See [Date#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) for documentation of formatting directives.

Comment: Do you mean you want to the date that represents Feb. 28 of a given year, regardless of whether it's a leap year? If so, `Date.new(<year here>, 2, 28)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
date = 'Feb. 29'
begin
  DateTime.parse(date)
rescue ArgumentError
  DateTime.parse('Feb. 28') if date == 'Feb. 29'
end
```